# Extract a group value and use it in the same regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I am just wondering if something like this is possible? Lets say I have a string

```
    length(hex)   crc
        |          |
       ---        ---
    ABC011abcdefghCRC
    ---   --------
     |        |
     id      body
```

The first 3 char (ABC) identifies a packet and the next 3 (011) give the total length of the packet. Is it possible to write a regex that extracts and use the length to match the complete packet?

If that is possible I would like to extend the regex to match multiple packets.

Comment: No.............

Comment: You have to extract the substring length and to convert it to an integer, then you have to extract the substring using the offset of the match and the given length.

Comment: You could easily do this in Perl, that something you're interested in ?

Comment: I think what you want is my C# implementation of Perl unpack, but unfortunately it isn't written yet.

Comment: Isn't it odd that a packet would be in ascii text, when it's usually a binary structure.

Comment: @sln I am limited to c#.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should even consider using regex for parsing tasks where structure is comletely separatable. Regex is designed for search, not for parsing, and good behavior is to avoid using it for parsing. Instead, parse it yourself, it will be easier and look simplier than some hijacked regex what only you can understand. Here is the example for multiple packets in single string:

```
var input = "ABC011abcdefghCRCABC011abcdefghCRCABC011abcdefghCRCABC011abcdefghCRCABC011abcdefghCRC";

var offset = 0;
while(offset< input.Length)
{
    var id = input.Substring(offset, 3);                offset+=3;
    var length = int.Parse(input.Substring(offset, 3)); offset+=3;
    var body = input.Substring(offset, length);         offset+=length;
    var crc = input.Substring(offset, 3);               offset+=3;
}
```

Comment: I'm more and less agree with your approach since it depends of the fact that the length of the substring that contains the length is always 3. However there's a leading zero in the example string.

Comment: The OP says the length is always 3, however it is also specified as being in hex... this code fails to run. Also, the length includes the extra fields...

Comment: I am doing something very similar. Using regex to identify the packet type and then extracting the length group and using that to extract the complete packet.